# Nvidia GTX960M external HDMI not working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have installed a 18.04 LTS Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire VN7-592G. This laptop is equipped with a Nvidia discrete graphic card, the GTX960M.
In the following, you will find the lspci result (grepping 3D and VGA):

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
```

As the driver is concerned, I have installed the Nvidia 390.116 drivers found on the Ubuntu repo.
Now, my problem is: I cannot see any external display attached to my HDMI port.

The result of the xrandr command is the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96*   59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

In a previous installation, I tried to switch to lightdm, to Wayland, to "addmode" to xrandr and activate the mode manually (as suggested in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1771185).
Nothing worked.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I've found a solution after drinking a cold beer and reading this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1771185/comments/26

The installation removed my xserver-xorg inputs. So, after installing the package suggested in the previous link, I issued the following:

```
 sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Now it works!!